# WPF ItemsControl databinding not working

Tags: wpf

I have following class structure and all classes implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```
class University
{
    List<Faculty> Faculties;
}

class Faculty
{
    string Name;
    List<Degree> Degrees;
    bool IsSelected
}

class Degree
{
    string Code;
    List<Subject> Subjects
    bool IsSelected
}

class Subject
{
    string Nme;
    string Code;
    bool IsSelected
}
```

When faculty is selected I want to display the degree names and their subject names in hire racy. (Panel will controls the current courses conducted by the university)

I have used `Itemcontol` for this perpose.

In my ViewModel I have object **CurrentFaculty** of type Faculty. I have bound the **CurrentFaculty** to my XAML

Following is my XAML code.

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentFaculty, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox  Margin="22,10,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <TextBlock Text="All"/>
                </CheckBox>
                <ItemsControl Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Degrees, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <CheckBox  Margin="22,10,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                </CheckBox>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Subjects, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox  Margin="42,10,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">                                              
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                            </CheckBox>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </StackPanel>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This is not working. What is the error on this??

Comment: did you checked the output window for any Binding Errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use current faculty as the itemssource for your first itemscontrol because it is only a single object, not a collection. I'm not sure why you are trying to anyway.

If you were to replace the parent itemscontrol with a ContentControl it should work as you expect as long as the CurrentFaculty is set correctly in the view model and your view datacontext is correctly set to your view model.

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding CurrentFaculty, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <CheckBox  Margin="22,10,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <TextBlock Text="All"/>
                    </CheckBox>
                    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Degrees, Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <CheckBox  Margin="22,10,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                    </CheckBox>
                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Subjects, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <CheckBox  Margin="42,10,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                                </CheckBox>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl>
                                </StackPanel>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    </ContentControl>
```

That should work, I can't promise you what it shows will look good, but that's up to you.